# Permission error after updating plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, cache

I have installed a plugin "Script Merge" after I edit the configuration for the plugin Joomla throws the following error:

> You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#820).

When I try to click on the link to edit it again.

I found a way to overcome this error by Disable cache (while Chrome DevTools is open) but why the error happening and what's the relation between cache and plugin.

Please Advice,

Comment: I would suggest you contact the developer of this plugin so they can assist you.

Comment: there is no problem with the plugin this is joomla issue, why it doesn't happen when the cache is empty or disabled?

Answer (score 1):

This error is generated by Joomla if a security check failed.

When you try to edit something in Joomla, it needs to go through the respective controller task. This controller then sets the id of the requested item in the user state after it has checked all ACL things. Afterwards it redirects to the edit view.

The display controller then checks that user state again for the requested id and if it's not set, raises this error.

So for some reason you're trying to access the edit view without first going properly through the controllers edit task.
One reason may be that you reloaded the page manually. Or maybe the session timed out (and thus user states got lost) while doing the edits.

Comment: this problem happens all the time even after log out and log in again, just this problem doesn't happen when I disable the cache!!!!

Comment: Works fine when I test it myself. Assuming you mean the one from Yireo.

Comment: After updating any plugin and close the edit page, when I click on the plugin again it gives this error: You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#804). How to fix this? I checked the responce code when clicking on the name of the plugin the code is: 303 See other

Comment: how to fix permission error in joomla 3.4.1?

Comment: I have no clue. I can't reproduce the behavior.
All I know is where this error is generated, that's what I explained in the answer. Why the user states aren't set/retrieved correctly and don't match, I don't know.
May be a botched installation or server.

Answer (score 0):

This has been an ongoing issue for some time but thanks to Phil Taylor and others should be fixed in Joomla 3.7:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/13516